# Windows 10 no text on desktop at startup

Tags: windows, fonts

On this particular Windows 10 machine, each time it boots up, the Text is missing on context menu, desktop shortcuts and even in control panel (start menu works fine). Only thing that resolves the issue is clicking on "Restore Default Font Settings" in "Font Settings" dialog. I've tried everything else, including deleting the font cache.

What is it that "Restore Default Font Settings" does that fixes it immediately? What's the permanent fix?

Note the shortcuts missing text, clock missing some text, no text in task manager - [blacked out some areas for privacy]
[image]